# Observing Electric and Magnetic Field Lines Around a Current Carrying Wire

Tags: electrostatics, magnetic-fields, electric-circuits, electric-fields, maxwell-equations

Referring to the idea of using grass seeds for observing electric field near current carrying wires from the following article,
[https://www.ifi.unicamp.br/~assis/Found-Phys-V29-p729-753(1999).pdf](https://www.ifi.unicamp.br/%7Eassis/Found-Phys-V29-p729-753(1999).pdf)

[image: grass seeds for electric field]

I am wondering how can we visualize both electric field and magnetic field simultaneously using both grass seeds and iron fillings around a current carrying wire. Since they will be perpendicular to each other will it be possible to practically execute this idea?